# Complex angle calculation with no reset of argument: continuous unbounded angle

Tags: matlab, simulink, number-theory

Consider the following example **Simulink** [(**Download example**)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9bhnuh9v15mfx0/mwe.slx?dl=0) system:

[image]

Input is a magnitude and an ever increasing angle, which will return two sine, the real and imaginary part as expected:

[image]

Calculating the Magntitude from real and imaginary part is no issue. Getting the angle in the domain **between -pi and pi** neither:

[image]

But I'm really struggling in calculating the **original *angle*** from the imaginary and real part. Do you have any ideas how to get rid of the discontinuity (yellow line, last picture)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this example?

[image]

```
function [ub_ang,ang] = phase_unwrap(re, im, theta)
%#codegen

ang = atan2(im,re);

tmp = [theta ang];

uang = unwrap(tmp);

ub_ang = uang(2);
```

Scope1 plot is below

[image]

Scope plot is below.

[image]

Comment: Apart from that you need to swap imaginary and real part in the `atan` calculation and you shouldn't use `real` and `imag` as variable names, as they are in-built functions - it works great!

Comment: Tjank you for your comment~

Answer (score 2):

[**Daniel's Solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392619/2605073) was exact what I was looking for, but in case the *DSP System Toolbox* is not available, like in case of my project partners, I came up with the following solution:

[image]

with

```
function [y, corr]  = phase_unwrap(zz,z,v)
%#codegen

d = diff([v,z,zz]);
if abs(d(1)) > pi
    y = sign(d(1));
    corr = -3/2*d(2);
else
    y = 0;
    corr = -3/2*d(1);
end

end
```

The *discrete time integrator* has the same sampling time as the *zero-order-hold* and a gain of `2*pi`.

The example output is satisfying, but **I still need to test it for the real case.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the block called `unwrap`. In case the toolbox is not available, this discrete implementation in simulink could be used:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Unfortunately it's for discrete time, but I'd guess there are no continous solutions anyway.

Comment: Though I have the toolbox, my project partners don't. I wonder how I could utilize the `unwrap` of the main matlab, which does the same, for Simulink.

Comment: I will take a closer look on tuesday, when I have access to simulink.

Comment: Therer is a matlab function block on User-defined functions group in simulink.

Comment: @김갑수 I'm aware of that, but it can't be used out opf the box.